# Javascript how to convert string to uint64 type

Tags: javascript

Javascript how to convert string to uint64 type , in c language i know as below solution:

```
char*[]="00";
uint64_t value;
memcpy(&value, chars, 8);
printf('%d',val);//result is 12336
```

I want to get the same result in javascript , please help

Comment: There is no such things like `uint64_t` in Javascript, If you want to convert a string to `number` or `float` you can use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` .

Comment: Don't know what you are trying to do but maybe this helps you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference/UInt64

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Numbers are always **64 bit Floating Point Numbers**. If you want to convert string to Number in Javascript you can use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` methods.